# iOS - Device's location from its cellular network

Tags: ios, iphone, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my project there is requirement to get user's location even though he/she turned off Location from Privacy.

Is there any way to get device's location from cellular network.

Also how can I get cellular network information in iOS?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No. If the user has disallowed location then you can't get their location

Comment: If someone has turned off their location information for privacy, it is unlikely  iOS would offer a way to work around it. It would be a serious flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no any official way to fetch the device location using cellular network i means through the `Public API` and not sure may some ways using `3rd Party Private API` but that will lead to immediate rejection by `Apple`. one of the `Private API` sample is there as well. [iphone-wireless](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/)